# Is it possible to get different plaintexts from a single ciphertext using different keys?

Tags: key-exchange

Suppose to have a chipertext that you can't decrypt, but you know that the plaintext can be A, B or C. Then arrives to you the key which is used to encrypt the chipertext. 
You can decrypt the chipertext and you get a plaintext equal to A. Is it possible that the original plaintext was B or C and you have received a key such that the decryption process gives as output a different plaintext (A)?

Of course, each A, B and C have a meaning to you, so if you decrypt something else (like D, E, F...) you understand that it is meaningless. Also, i want to add that the source from which you receive the key cannot be trusted, but this doesn't mean that the key is always incorrect.

For clarification:

1. I receive a ciphertext I can't decrypt
2. I receive a key to decrypt the ciphertext
3. I decrypt the ciphertext with the key from step 2 and get the plaintext

How can I be sure that the plaintext obtained is infact the one previously encrypted if I can't trust the source from which I get the key and the ciphertext?

Comment: I do not use any algorithm right now, but if you can point to me anyone for which this couldn't happen, i will be very glad to hear that.

Comment: It is possible to have encryption schemes like this. It's called equivocal encryption. The one time pad is for example fully equivocable. However, full equivocability requires the key to have the same length as the message. There are weaker notions of partial equivocability and somewhere equivocability. (I'll write an answer once I'm not on mobile, unless someone's faster than I am.)

Comment: I guess it's important to clarify: do you want this property? Or do you want to prevent it?

Comment: You can make an allowance in the system that half the message is padding, then key A decrypts one half, key B decrypts the other half.

Comment: I update the question in order to explain some misunderstanding, sorry for this.
Just to be clear. I want to avoid this from happening, so what type of algorithm should i use? Or is just sufficient to have a key with different lenght from the ciphertext?

Comment: @DanieleBuonadonna If you want to avoid this, all you need to do is use a standard secure block cipher like AES. To avoid malleability issues, use an authenticated mode like GCM.

Comment: If the untrusted server is imagined as a webserver that usually tries to do its job, but sometimes is used by the TLA to stitch people up then something like this might work. You have pre arranged two keys with Bob, and want to download a big file from them, Bob uploads a long un guessable web address to the untrusted server, encrypted with key 1, and uploads the file to some other server encrypted with key 2.

Comment: some related questions: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/ciphers-providing-deniable-encryption?r=SearchResults and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/deniable-encryption-from-simple-primitives?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I be sure that the plaintext obtained is in fact the one previously encrypted if I can't trust the source from which I get the key and the ciphertext?

In general you cannot. The standard security notions of do not imply any *binding*. I.e., the definitions do not rule out that, given a key $k$ and a ciphertext $c \gets \operatorname{Enc}(k,m)$ an attacker might be able to find a key $k'$, such that $m' = \operatorname{Dec}(k',c)$ for some $m' \neq m$.
In fact, for many encryption schemes, such as block ciphers in some non-authenticated mode of operation, or a stream-cipher this is always possible, since decryption will always succeed with any key. What differs between different schemes is how much control an attacker may have over $m'$. But for many schemes *some* control, such as ensuring that a few bits have specific values is certainly possible.

Opening an encryption scheme to a different value than was originally encrypted is called *equivocation*. The one-time pad as described by AleksanderRas is an extreme of an equivocal encryption scheme, being *fully equivocal.
I.e., for any ciphertext $c$ and any plaintext $m'$ it is possible to find a key $k'$, such that $\operatorname{Dec}(k',c)=m'$. Being equivocal is in fact a useful property of an encryption scheme in applications such as secure multi-party computation. However, being fully equivocal actually implies the scheme must
necessarily have a key size which is as large as the message size. There are relaxed notions of [somewhere equivocal](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1250) and [non-committing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/521) encryption.

That name of that last notion brings us to the fact that you do in fact want your encryption scheme to **not** be equivocal. The opposite of an equivocal encryption scheme would be a committing encryption scheme, where the ciphertext serves as a commitment to the plaintext.

At this point your question and in particular the "key-exchange" tag lead me to believe that you are probably not actually looking for an encryption scheme, but a commitment scheme. A commitment scheme allows one party to *commit* to a message $m$ in a commitment $c \gets \operatorname{Com}(m;r)$. Such a commitment can later be *opened* usually by revealing the randomness $r$ used in the commitment.

A commitment scheme has two important properties:

1. It is **hiding**, meaning that $c$ reveals nothing about $m$.
2. It is **binding**, meaning that it is infeasible to equivocate, i.e., to open the commitment $c$ to a message $m'\neq m$.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible (as Maeher correctly pointed out) to have such a property.

Probably the most known encryption system with this property is the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). It has some limitations, like the key has to be (cryptographically secure) random and the same length as the plaintext.

**Procedure:**

1. Encrypt a message $m_1$ with key $k_1$
2. Now we have a ciphertext $c$
3. It's now possible to decrypt the ciphertext $c$ with:

   a. The (correct) key $k_1$ and get the resulting message $m_1$

   b. The (incorrect) key $k_2$ and get a different message $m_2$

The problem is, that we can not be sure which key was originally used to encrypt the message $m_1$, because both decryptions could be valid (= make sense).

Let's directly take the [example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#Example):

1. Alice want's to send a message ($m_1$) to Bob

   > HELLO
2. She chooses the key ($k_1$)

   > XMCKL
3. By using modular addition (see the example in wikipedia if this step is unclear) we get the ciphertext $c_1$

   > EQNVZ
4. Bob can now decrypt the ciphertext $c_1$ with the key

   a. $k_1$ (XMCKL) and obtain the intended plaintext message $m_1$

   > HELLO

   b. $k_2$ (TQURI) and obtain a different message $m_2$

   > LATER

This is possible because both the word *HELLO* and *LATER* have 5 characters. It's actually possible to decrypt any ciphertext ($c_1$) to any given plaintext ($m_n$) with the same length.

Comment: This fails the last part: if I can't trust the source.

Comment: You can use [Pedersen commitment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64437/what-is-a-pedersen-commitment) on the key.